# ContextMenu item extension did not work in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, delphi, winapi, contextmenu

My software works as shell extension, and register himself for showing on Background/Directory and Desktop right click menu. I developing on Win XP and it's works good, but now when i testing it on Windows 7, does not want work well. Context item exists only on Desktop right click menu, but does not on Background/Directory. Need help!

Here is reg function in Delphi, but examples on any language accepted, i can show extension DLL src if needed!

```
const
  CLSID_ContextMenu = '{AB69D961-B907-11D0-B8FA-A85800C10000}';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    with Reg do
    begin
      RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
      OpenKey('\CLSID\' + CLSID_ContextMenu, True);
      WriteString('', 'Context Menu Shell Extension');
      OpenKey('\CLSID\' + CLSID_ContextMenu + '\InProcServer32', True);
      WriteString('', ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Project1.dll');
      WriteString('ThreadingModel', 'Apartment');
      CreateKey('\Directory\Background\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\' + CLSID_ContextMenu);
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Windows 7 changed a lot, I remember the location for printer context menu changed as well...

Comment: Are you sure the Windows 7 system isn't running a 64-bit Explorer? If you're developing on XP you're almost certainly on 32 bit. Windows 7 is most commonly found in 64 bit varieties, and many shell extensions written against 32 bit Explorer will fail to register with 64 bit Explorer.

Comment: Its 32 bit certainly! The problem is, that it's successfully registered but work only on desktop, not in folder background like in xp

Comment: Are you aware that your shell extension cannot work on 64 bit? Does that matter to you?

Comment: i need 64 bit support of course, but firstly i need to resolve problem with context menu! I saw your previous post about XE2 and 64 compiler, thanks. Do I must just update my IDE and compile project in it or some code changes required?

Comment: Well, you may need some code changes for x64. But maybe not much. Depends on how much pointer hacking you do. If your code is well written then it's just a simple re-compile for a different target platform.

Comment: Please add the answer as an answer and remove it from the question

Comment: You definitely need a 64bit compiler to write Shell Extensions for 64bit Windows Explorer. However, a 32bit Shell Extension will work in 32bit Windows Explorer (which is available on a 64bit system if WOW64 is installed), but a user of a 64bit system is not likely to use that flavor of Windows Explorer very often, if ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! In XP i wrote to

```
\Directory\Background\Shell**Ex**\**ContextMenuHandlers**\CLSID
```

but in Windows 7 the path should be like

```
\Directory\Background\Shell\Name of your app\command
```

and in command we put a path to our app in double quotes "%path%".:)

Answer (score 2):

You are making some major mistakes with your use of `TRegistry`.

You are not specifying any `Access` rights, so it defaults to `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, which is restricted to admins only. Admin users in Vista and later do not have full admin rights like they did in XP. Make sure your app is running in an elevated state if UAC is enabled.
  Either right-click on the .exe and choose "Run as administrator", or give your .exe a UAC manifest that specifies "requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator". If you do not want your main app to run elevated, then move the Registry logic into a separate .exe or COM object that you can then run elevated when needed.

You are writing to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Do not do that. MSDN says as much. You can *read* from it, but do not *write* to it. You need to write to either `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead, depending on whether you need to register your Shell Extension for the current user or all users.

You are ignoring the return value of `OpenKey()`and `CreateKey()` to make sure the keys are opened/created successfully before then writing to them.

Comment: Thanks for advices, but i dont agree with them. If you look at msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110(v=vs.85).aspx , you will see that i must write exactly in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. About access writes, i have tried to run as Admin, and  Context item was added, but only on the Desktop. Not in folders background.

Comment: CLASSES_ROOT is a merged view of [CURRENT_USER|LOCAL_MACHINE]\Software\Classes and all older code samples and documentation just lists it as HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT but that does not mean you should write there (Writing there was fine for a machine wide install in a pre x64/UAC/registry reflection&redirection world where "everyone" was admin)

Comment: KEY_ALL_ACCESS seems reasonable for installing.  The registry code already is in a registration function. What you say about CLASSES_ROOT is reasonable.

Comment: Most documentation that talks about registrations refer to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` only for simplicity, but MSDN has more detailed info about how `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` itself works and how it should be used in practice. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx